# InstallShield 2012 internal error

Tags: asp.net, installshield

I have visual studio 2012 and thus am using InstallShield limited edition to create a .MSI.
I have a web application in ASP.NET with webforms.

I created an InstallShield project in my solution and ran through the project assistant.
I added the primary output, the source files, the debug symbols and the content files in the "Files" section.
I require .NET framework 4.0 and sql server 2008 to be installed and that the OS is Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 or windows 7 (I'm not sure about that but i thought i could test the msi file on my computer first).
I created a desktop shortcut linked to the primary output (not useful but just out of curiosity).

That's everything I did and when I try to "Install" it, I have a 5036 internal build error. Description of the error on http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/ is useless: 
"Check the Knowledge Base for information about this error, or request technical support."

I don't know what I did wrong. Or maybe I just didn't understand something fundamental. That's why I'm asking you: What did I miss?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it by creating a new solution, adding the InstallShield project first and then my other projects.

Found the solution from a 2005 forum post here: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-142987.html