# Install Sheild LE -4340 Internal Build Error Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have an issue with building an MSI with Install Shield LE in Visual Studio.  The error says "-4340: Internal Build Error", but the link to Flexera is worthless.  I tried the suggestion in another post to add the installer project to a fresh solution and then my .Net projects after, but that did not help.  That suggestion can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231734/installshield-2012-internal-error)

I have not found a *single* repeatable cause of the issue, it does not seem to happen because of any one thing.  I'm trying to build an installer for a Windows Service.

Comment: I have the same issue. It doesn't seem to be a code issue. I built the setup just fine, then 10 minutes later....same error as you. I even loaded my project fresh from source control with no dice. I'm going to try whacking the setup project and creating a new one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got that error too. In order to fix it i rebuild my solution in Release configuration instead of Debug one.

Comment: I had a similar experience, though I had to go one step futher and unload/reload the Installshield project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Unloading it and then loading it back helped me out too.  The whole InstallShield has been a totally big pain to use....and it keeps breaking for apparently no reason.  I have no idea why someone would buy the professional version when the free version is so aggravating to use.

Comment: Just adding to Rudean's answer, I found that after rebuilding in Release to get rid of the error, I could then switch back to Debug and it then worked fine.  I second the remarks about how much of a pain ISLE is.

Comment: You may have to repeat the clean-rebuild-rollback-change configuration-undo-sprinkle goat's blood ritual several million times before the project decides it will now magically rebuild without errors.

Comment: Fails frequently with this error for me too. I always 'Clean' before 'Build' but that does not always help. I just exit VS2013 and restart it. Then it always works at least once.

Answer (score 9):

All I did is restart Visual Studio.  For some reason that worked for me.

Comment: I did while counting my Rosary beads.  That seemed to do it.

Comment: sometimes you have to resort to deific methods.  =)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is slightly different:

1. Close and launch Visual Studio, open solution then
2. Rebuild with Release configuration AND
3. Unload/load InstallShield

**Setup**:
Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10, Visual C#

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, it was because I added an executable for extra dialogs to be run after the install.  I told install shield to run the executable, but I didn't add it to the list of files to deploy.
When I added it to the files, the error went away.

It could be that when users switch to "debug" that they have a build of the executable in debug mode, but they never built it in release mode.

It would be nice if flexera produced a normal error message for my case at least.   i.e.  "You said to run XYZ, but XYZ is not found in the file list"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by deleting a previous build. It looks like Visual Studio wasn't able to delete the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late to this post... but I will post the solution in case others run into the problem. I worked with Flexera on this problem and they provided a fix for it. Download and install IS 2016 SP1 or newer and the problem is solved! Read all about it at
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?220123-ISDEV-error-4340-Internal-build-error&p=509912

Answer (score 0):

I just had this again for the x-thousandth time.  Normally the rebuild approach works, or failing that restarting VS, but this time I actually had to restart Windows to get it working again.  Hope that helps someone, I was starting to really think it wasn't going to work again this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to unload/reload the InstallShield project in order for it to build.

Comment: That probably should only happen if you don't have local admin rights

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error when I forget to **start Visual Studio with Administrator privileges**.